# Why does onItemLongClickreturn false?

Tags: android

Why does onItemLongClickreturn false and its boolean, and onItemClick is void and do not return anything ?

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //Long click event 
        return false;
    }
});  


listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener` returns true, if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()` returns `false`, because your aren't consuming the `callback`. If you want to return `true`, then you have to consume it.